# golang sql query timeout

Tags: mysql, go, timeout

I want to return when the query is not returned on DBMS against the firewall.

First, I set the code

```
c, err := sql.Open("mysql",dbid+":"+dbps+"@tcp("+dbip[0]+":"+dbpt+")/"+dbnm+"?timeout=5s")
```

but, not do that.

Second, I used the function in the context package.

```
 ctx, cancel := content.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second * 10)
 ret, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "Select * from aaaa")
```

It catched timeout after 10 seconds, but evaluated the error message

> "no route to host"

I try to query one more time.

How to coding evaluate timeout when read and write queries send?

Comment: Your problem is completely unrelated to a timeout. The problem, exactly as the error message says, is that there's no route to the host. Whichever database server you're trying to connect to, is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that the **Firewall is blocking the route to the database**. Timeout is obvious since the host itself is unreachable. The evaluation for 10 seconds is based on the timer you have written and you are not getting Timeout as the evaluated error since firewall is blocking your DBHost.

Comment: I really appreciate to you~, Thank you^^